# Como restar un valor desde una tabla distinta y actualizar el valor en Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

En mi vista tengo un listado de libros que adquiere un cliente a pagos diferidos, los datos relevantes en esta pregunta son Costo Original (donde se guarda el valor real del libro) y Costo Restante (donde se muestra el costo restado por los pagos).
lo que quiero lograr es que cada vez que un cliente realice un pago este le descuente al costo original y se guarde o actualice en la base de datos de manera automática, anteriormente lo hacia de manera manual restando los valores y después colocarlo en un input para actualizarlo,

Como lograría esto?

**Tabla Libros**

```
$table->float('valorOriginal', 10, 2);
$table->float('valorRestado', 10, 2);
$table->unsignedBigInteger('client_id');
$table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');
```

**Tabla Pagos**

```
$table->float('pago', 10, 2);
$table->unsignedBigInteger('libro_id')->nullable()->default(null);
$table->foreign('libro_id')->references('id')->on('libros')->onDelete('cascade');
```

**Método -Store- del controlador "PagosController"**

```
$pay = new Pago();
$pay->libro_id= $request->input('libro_id');
$pay->pago= $request->input('pago');

$pay->save();
```

Comment: Que tal Antonio, tu pregunta puede ser mal recibida por la comunidad debido a que no has puesto lo que has intentado hacer por ti mismo y esto puede llevar a que nadie te ayude, por favor edita tu pregunta y pega el código que has hecho

Comment: hola @TheVicShow gracias por la recomendación, sinceramente no tenia idea de como hacer algo como esto, para futuras preguntas pondré los avances que tenga, gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada que realices un pago inmediatamente actualizas el valor original

```
$pay = new Pago();
    $pay->libro_id= $request->input('libro_id');
    $pay->pago= $request->input('pago');

$libro=libroModel::where('id',$idLibro)->first();
$libro->valorOriginal-=$request->input('pago');
$libro->save();
$pay->save();
```

Comment: me ayudo mucho, muchas gracias :)